# Create an edge on the basis of column value in a csv in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have two csv files. The first one 'user_features.csv' contains 'nodes' and their 14 features like following:

```
node_id,f1,f2,f3,f4,....f13 

1045,   2, 3,  4, 5,.... 31    
5042,   1, 2,  3, 4,.....25
```

I was able to load this in Neo4j using following:

```
using commit periodic 10000
load csv with headers from "file:///user_features.csv" as linecsv
create (n:user_features {name: linecsv.node_id, f1: linecsv.f1 .....})
```

Now, I have a second file called 'train.csv' with data in the following shape:

```
node1_id,node2_id,is_related

1045,5042,1  
1045,134,0
```

Here 'is_related' field suggests that there is a connection between node1_id and node2_id.

I want to establish the relationship on the loaded graph using this data. But I am not able to understand how to use the value of 'is_related' field. Will the Where clause be helpful in this scenario ?

There is another way where I have modified the "train.csv" file by filtering  on 'is_related' field = 1 in the graph database and it works.

But is it possible to use the value of the column 'is_related' to create an edge between node1 and node2 on the graph?

Comment: I'm afraid we can't tell you how to use `is_related`, since you have not told us what it means nor what your desired neo4j data model is.

Comment: @cybersam: I have edited the question, please let me know if it is understandable. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems strange that the CSV file bothers to have rows with the `is_related` value of 0 if you are supposed to do nothing with such rows. Why not just leave those rows out (and eliminate the `is_related` column entirely)?

However, if you truly only want to create, say, a `RELATED_TO` relationship when `is_related` is 1, you can do something like this:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///train.csv" AS row
WITH row
WHERE row.is_related = 1
MATCH (n:user_features {name: row.node1_id}), (m:user_features {name: row.node2_id})
MERGE (n)-[:RELATED_TO]->(m)
```

Also, this query would be faster if you have an [index](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/index/) on `:user_features(name)`.

Comment: I tried this: but got the following Error. Neo.DatabaseError.General.UnknownError: No RelationshipState for added relationship!

Comment: Are you using the latest neo4j version?